# Desactivar Google Analytics al rechazar cookies

Tags: javascript, html5, google-analytics

He insertado el Tag en el head de mi web

```
 <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
 <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'idxxxxxxxxxxxx');
 </script>
```

Funciona correctamente, y he visto en Google que para desactivar la medicion se utiliza
antes de llamar a la funcion gtag() la siguiente instrucción.

```
 window['ga-disable-idxxxxxxxxxxxx']=true;
```

Si la inserto, es correcto, no se envían datos.
Ahora bien, mi intención era dejar esto por defecto, es decir, no activado, y cuando el usuario haga click en un botón **aceptar cookies** en mi documento html(el típico banner de cookies), entonces si se active y comience el analisis. Entonces, lo que tengo es lo siguiente.

```
<head>
  <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=xxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    window['ga-disable-xxxxxxxxxxxx']=true;

    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'xxxxxxxxxxxx');
   </script>
 </head>
```

Y en mi JS para el botón de aceptar cookies :

```
botonAceptarCookies.addEventListener('click', () => {

window['ga-disable-xxxxxxxxxxxx']=undefined;


avisoCookies.classList.remove('activo');
fondoAvisoCookies.classList.remove('activo');

localStorage.setItem('cookies-aceptadas', true);

dataLayer.push({'event': 'cookies-aceptadas'});
});
```

Esto realmente no funciona y aunque le de a aceptar parece que predomina **window['ga-disable-xxxxxxxxxxxx']=true;** del head.

¿Como puedria configurar para que no analice hasta aceptar las cookies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente he descubierto las posibilidades de Google tag en cuanto a Consentimientos. Basicamente añadiendo lo siguiente antes de la llamada a gtag() el analisis para ads y para analytics esta desactivado:

```
 <!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXXXXX"> 
 </script>
 <script>
 window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
 function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

 gtag('consent', 'default', {
'ad_storage': 'denied',
'analytics_storage': 'denied'
});

gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXXX');
```

Para activarlo, he añadido el siguinte script A mi evento 'click' del banner cookies:

```
 gtag('consent', 'update',{
'ad_storage': 'granted',
'analytics_storage': 'granted'
});
```

Dejo enlace a la documentación por si es de utilidad para otros

[Google consent](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/devguides/consent?hl=en#advanced_consent_features)